# Block access based on SESSION

Tags: php, session

I am working on a user based website. So, I have different sections for different users. I want that if the session username is "Rock", he shouldn't be able to access other user's profile say "Gray".

So,

```
if $_session['username']=="rock"
{
//BLOCK ACCESS TO OTHER FILES IN FOLDER PLACED IN DIRECTORY
}
```

How do I do that?

Thank you

Comment: by access I mean by simply typing it out in the URL like goal.com/user/gray.

Answer (score 0):

On gray's page you could have:

```
if($_SESSION['username'] != 'gray'){
     header('Location: http://www.goal.com/');
     exit;
}
```

If you want to allow certain people to access gray's page you could have an array with the people that can access it...

```
$allowed = array('bob', 'james');

if(!in_array($_SESSION['username'], $allowed)){
     header('Location: http://www.goal.com/');
     exit;
}
```

Or the other way around, if you only want to deny certain people access you could have.

```
$blocked = array('rock', 'pop');

if(in_array($_SESSION['username'], $blocked)){
     header('Location: http://www.goal.com/');
     exit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple users you can't hard-code this type of thing.

Assuming your using a database...

```
// Comes from database
$username = $row['username'];

// Check session
if ($username !== $_SESSION['username']) {
    header("Location: /access/denied/page/");
    exit();
}
```